# The argument passed inside a function becomes undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query, mutation

```
 const onCellClick = p => {
    const policyId = p?.id;
    const updatedBy = p?.row?.updated_by;
    console.log(updatedBy, "updatedBy");
    applyPolicies(policyId, updatedBy);
  };
```

This is the another function where I am doing an API call with pID and updatedBy, the updatedBy becomes undefined where pID is fine.

```
export const useApplyPolicyMutation = () => {
  return useMutation(
    (pID, updatedBy) => {
      console.log(updatedBy, "updatedByinquery");
      console.log(pID, "pID");
      const workspaceId = getWS();
      const payload = {
        workspace_id: workspaceId,
        policy_id: pID,
        updated_by: updatedBy
      };
      customPost("/policymanagement/api/v1/auto-discover/add-policy", payload);
    }
```

Comment: Without seeing your data, it's hard to tell. Most probably either the `row` field is nullish or the `updated_by` field is nullish or there's a typo in the data and the field name isn't `updated_by`.

Comment: You should edit your question to include this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`useMutation`](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/useMutation) can only take one argument as payload, so you need to wrap it in an object:

```
export const useApplyPolicyMutation = () => {
  return useMutation(
-    (pID, updatedBy) => {
+    ({ pID, updatedBy }) => {
```

```
- applyPolicies(policyId, updatedBy);
+ applyPolicies({ pID: policyId, updatedBy });
```